# Which layout is best with cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

We are right now analysing cytoscape.js for our requirements and we wished to understand which layout extension out of http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions will be good for us. Can any one please help/guide us in choosing layouts?

We are thinking of having more than one layout depending on the use case  however with each layout we would always like to have high performance with quick graph rendering.

Use Cases:-

1) We want to display 20,000 interactions(edges) and probably 40,000 
   interactors(nodes) at maximum level, we can reduce that down if it's 
   too much for any layout to handle.

Would "cise" and "fcose" be alright for this ?

2) Graph should spread out in the view port making use of any empty space 
   if small number of nodes/edges are displayed, I think we need to do 
   this by ourselves but just in case if it comes out of the box.

Would "spread" be alright for this ?

3) Non crossing edges.

Would "ngraph.forcelayout" be alright for this ?

4) We would need a functionality where there would be parent-child 
   relationship for edges so that when user clicks on parent edge,child 
   edges appear and vice versa.

Which layout would be best for this use case ?

Answer (score 2):

Which layout extension would be the best highly depends on what kind of graph you are about to visualize. You would probably need to try a few and see what works best.

For a DAG the best (from my experience) layout is [Dagre](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre).

Dependencies:

```html
    <script src="lib/cyjs/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/cyjs/dagre.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/cyjs/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
```

Config:

```
layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
    rankDir: 'LR',
}
```

For auto-zooming you would use `.fit()` method on the `cytoscape` instance.

```js
let cy = cytoscape(options);
...
cy.fit(cy.elements());
```

More generally, `.elements()`, `.nodes()`, `.edges()`, `.$()` can be used to get a [collection](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.collection) of graph elements which can be used to show/hide, select/deselect, and fit-to. Collections also support all sorts of graph navigation functionality like fanin/fanout tree, which can be used to get a very pleasing graph exploration UI.

To give a taste of the collection API, a highlighting of a fanin + fanout tree of the selected node(s) would be something like

```js
let n = cy.$('node:selected');
if (n != null) {
    // find elements to be displayed
    let ns = n
        .predecessors()
        .union(n)
        .union(n.predecessors().union(n).successors());

    // display them
    ns.style("display", "element");

    // hide the rest of the graph
    cy
        .elements()
        .not(ns)
        .style("display", "none");

    // fit the view port to the displayed elements
    cy
        .fit(ns.union(ns.incomers())
        .union(ns.outgoers()));
}
```